# how to find duplicate rows with respect of 2 column in 2 different dataset

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to find duplicate rows with respect of 2 column in 2 different dataset.

```
      ACTDUR     PERNO    TRPDUR     mode
         1         1        10       3
         1         1        8       7
         1        10        8       7
         1         2        9       4
         2         3        11       30
         2         4        12       13


       ACTDUR     PERNO    TRPDUR    mode
         1         10        10       13
         1         8         11       3
         2         1         12       13
```

duplicate row with respect of column SAMPN and time,

```
       ACTDUR     PERNO    TRPDUR     mode
         1         1        10       3
         1         10       10       13
         2         4        12       13
         2         1        12       13
```

here is a part of my real data that I am working on. here duplicated is with respect of ACTDUR and TRPDUR.

data1:

```
structure(list(SAMPN = c(14, 14, 14, 14, 21, 21, 38, 38, 38, 
38, 38), PERNO = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4), PLANO = c(6, 
7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2), loop = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2), TRPDUR = c(12, 23, 20, 12, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10), ACTDUR = c(47, 55, 48, 749, 210, 664, 50, 934, 50, 934, 
50)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

dput(data1[10:26,])

```
structure(list(SAMPN = c(19, 19, 19, 21, 21, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37), PERNO = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), PLANO = c(4, 7, 8, 3, 4, 3, 
4, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 7), loop = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3), TRPDUR = c(5, 11, 5, 20, 10, 
2, 12, 15, 10, 2, 12, 15, 10, 2, 12, 15, 10), ACTDUR = c(516, 
75, 516, 210, 664, 1, 75, 255, 599, 1, 75, 255, 599, 1, 75, 255, 
599)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

out put should be for SAMPN==21
```

Comment: my bad, just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can bind the two rows together with unique `id`, `group_by` `SAMPN` and `time` and select rows which have more than 1 distinct `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2, .id = "id") %>%
     group_by(SAMPN, time) %>%
     filter(n_distinct(id) > 1) %>%
     select(-id)

#  SAMPN PERNO  time  mode
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1    10     3
#2     2     4    12    13
#3     1    10    10    13
#4     2     1    12    13
```

Comment: in first data frame there is a pair of duplicate rows

Comment: I want the out put to be from both dataset

Comment: @hghg I see. I have updated the answer based on that.

Comment: still same problem, it select duplicates just in one of them too

Comment: I think, we can let go off `duplicated` and just use `n_distinct` to `filter`, it should return the same result. Can you check if it changes anything in your data, gives expected output atleast for the data shared.

Comment: plz check the updated data, duplicate for TRPDUR and ACTDUR not SAMPN and time

Comment: @hghg `bind_rows(df1, df2, .id = "id") %>%
  group_by(TRPDUR, ACTDUR) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(id) > 1) ` works for me gives me 4 rows with `SAMPN == 21` and different id's. Maybe add ` %>% arrange(TRPDUR, ACTDUR)` to clearly see the output. What output do you get?

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`.  We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` to rbind the two datasets while creating an 'id' column, grouped by 'ACTDUR', 'TRPDUR', subset the data.table  where the number of distinct elements of 'id' is greater than 1

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), idcol = 'id')[, .SD[uniqueN(id) > 1],
    .(ACTDUR, TRPDUR)][, id := NULL][]
#  ACTDUR TRPDUR PERNO mode
#1:      1     10     1    3
#2:      1     10    10   13
#3:      2     12     4   13
#4:      2     12     1   13
```

---

We can also do this in `base R`

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, df1[c(1, 3)])
v2 <- do.call(paste, df2[c(1, 3)])
v3 <- intersect(v1, v2)
rbind(df1[v1 %in% v3,], df2[v2 %in% v3,])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ACTDUR = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), PERNO = c(1L, 
1L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L), TRPDUR = c(10L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L), 
    mode = c(3L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 30L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(ACTDUR = c(1L, 1L, 2L), PERNO = c(10L, 8L, 1L), 
    TRPDUR = 10:12, mode = c(13L, 3L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```